# Are there morphological rules to "build" transitive/interactive verb pairs?

Tags: verbs, morphology

教える/教わる、伝える/伝わる
届ける/届く、開ける/開く
預ける/預かる、見つける/見つかる
回す/回る、出す/出る、起こす/起きる
隠す/隠れる
乗せる/乗る
落とす/落ちる
当てる/当たる
決める/決まる、暖める/暖まる
冷やす/冷える、燃やす/燃える
消す/消える
降りる/降ろす
入れる/入る
... are pairs of transitive/intensive verbs with related meanings.
It feels like there are simple rules to "convert" from one verb to the other in such pairs... but not in all the cases.
Are there such rules? Or do we just have to remember arbitrary combinations?
What are the historical reasons of why those verbs "look" like this?

Answer (score 1):

intensive/transitive
 1. -ARU/-U　塞がる/塞ぐ
 2. -ARU/-ERU　預かる/預ける, 当たる/当てる, 決まる/決める
 3. -U/-ERU　開く/開ける, 届く/届ける
 4. -ERU/-U　取れる/取る
 5. -ERU/-ASU　出る/出す, 冷える/冷やす
 6. -RERU/-SU　隠れる/隠す, 消える/消す
 7. -U/-ASU　乾く/乾かす
 8. -IRU/-ASU　延びる/延ばす
 9. -IRU/-OSU　起きる/起こす, 落ちる/落とす, 降りる/降ろす
 10. -RU/-SU　回る/回す
 11. -RU/-SERU　乗る/乗せる
 12. -IERU/-ESU　消える/消す

this website will help you;) ⇒"http://w01.i-next.ne.jp/~g140179870/jita.html"