# Is there any pattern to tell which verb of the two is transitive and which is intransitive?

Tags: verbs, transitivity, pattern

Let me first explain what I mean. Take these two pairs for example:

> 付く、付ける (the first one is **intransitive**, the second one is
> **transitive**)
>
> 抜く、抜ける (the first one is **transitive**, the second on is
> **intransitive**)

(of course, つく has a lot of meanings/homophones, but this is a different question... or not?)

So, the question now becomes: **is there a pattern here, or at least a statistics to try and predict without context if in a verb pair, say with ～く/～ける , which one is transitive and which one is intransitive?**

Possibly this all just comes down to memorization, but who knows? I don't. Yet.

---

P.S. I tried to find if this has been asked before and found some partial answers: [how to 'build' these pairs](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/41430/are-there-morphological-rules-to-build-transitive-interactive-verb-pairs), [whether all verbs come in such pairs](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/55754/existence-of-transitive-intransitive-pairs), and even a very interesting and possibly related explanation about the [history of okurigana and verb conjugations](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/21042/are-there-any-patterns-for-okurigana), but these are all... well, as I said, partial

Having created the question, I found three more related questions in the "Related" section: [about etymology](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/12527/etymology-of-transitive-intransitive-verb-pairs?rq=1), [about -eru/-aru verbs specifically](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/586/about-eru-and-aru-verb-pairs-that-are-not-transitive-intransitive-counterpart?rq=1), and [about if there is a transitive/intransitive pattern in general](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/14861/%E3%81%A8%E3%81%BE%E3%82%8B-%E3%81%A8%E3%82%81%E3%82%8B-and-such-pairs-of-verbs?rq=1), and so far it has proven especially informative for me:

> -e(ru) - a kind of transitivity flipper, it can make transitives intransitive or intransitives transitive. An example of the first is
> さける ('split open', compare さく 'tear'), and an example of the second is
> つける ('attach', compare つく 'stick to').
>
> Many of these pairs, とめる~とまる included, seem to have had these
> morphemes added to both members.
>
> I'm not sure this is a grammatical process, at least any more; none of
> these morphemes are still productive as far as I know. You're probably
> best off remembering each word as a single lexical unit, especially
> considering the fact that there's a good deal of variation among what
> pairs up with what.

However, there might still be more information to this, or additional sources that the community might share

Comment: There is some general [patterns](https://www.wasabi-jpn.com/japanese-grammar/intransitive-verbs-vs-transitive-verbs/), but I wouldn't focus on them.

Comment: @Simon, this is actually a good source nonetheless, thank you. So, basically, if we summarize just the indicators, -aru and -reru are always intransitive, -su are always transitive

Comment: @Vladimir Those are not rules, and will have exceptions. So although you might be able to guess a lot correctly, it is still safer to look them up. For example 抜け出す is intransitive and しかる, 忘れる are transitive.

Comment: @Shurim, thank you, haven't thought about these. So, basically, it's better to just emorize them one by one, be careful and check yourself